# Play movies found on USB stick on boot

Tags: video, media-server, composite-video, media

I'd like to connect a RPi2 to an old TV (via composite) and use it as media player.

With a plugged USB stick containing movies (avi files, DivX or other formats, etc.), I would like the RPi to auto-play the first movie found on USB stick (on boot, i.e. it will start without user interaction).

**1. What solution is usually used for this media player purpose?**

**2. As I will have no keyboard connected, what would you use to allow the user to browse the movies?** (next/previous movie, pause, fast forward, etc.) Just a mouse? something else?

Comment: Do you want to use the RPi for other purposes? I had a script set up to play a looping video on boot with a RPi Zero. I used OMXplayer, so didn't need a GUI installed. It worked fine, although I've since upgraded my solution. If you use a RPi with a network connection, you can still remote in (e.g. using ssh) and do other things as it plays videos on the display.

Comment: use adafruit video looper link below https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-video-looper/overview

Comment: @ThomasJoseph FYI, your answer was deleted not because it was wrong, but because it was too short. You can expand it a bit (explain what video player is used, what are the major installation steps, etc.) and then undelete it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a python script to autorun, usually kodi is used.
2. Use an ir remote.

Comment: Is there a distro that I could just put on a µSD card, thus without requiring manual scripting? I would use mouse (I don't have an IR remote, anyway how could I connect it to RPi)?

Comment: Nope, and a mouse might work. Also a USB receiver for the ir remote.